# Is it possible to use a Google web app from a Chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I've made a google script and deployed it as a web app (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps). I was wondering if it is possible to interface with this app through a chrome extension. I've tried using the "iframe", "webview", and "meta" tags to get the app into my extension, but I haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You cant iframe it. At most you can call a content script url with ajax.